# Spark: Reading avro file without com.databricks.spark.avro

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to read the avro file in spark but unfortunately the cluster in my company does not have com.databricks.spark.avro.

So I tried

```
spark-shell --package com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:0.1.
```

This gives unresolved dependency

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._ is not supported.
```

Also tried

```
spark-shell --jar spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar
```

This does not open the shell.

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("dirpath/*.avro") returns 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.avro. Please find an Avro package at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html;
```

spark.read.avro("dirpath/*.avro") returns
error: value avro is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader

This table is so big(avro table partitioned on date/field1/field2 and running as spark.sql("") returns GC overhead.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its not `--package` it's `--packages`.

Secondly, version seems to be incomplete.

> spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1

Then import the avro essential.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs the way how you specify the avro jars onto the cluster. If you place databricks jars as part of spark classpath it makes it available to driver and executors but if you use some kind of launcher like spark launcher or Apache Livy you have to explicitly add as part of Spark Session. I resolved it like adding extra properties

```
  sparkLauncher.setConf("spark.driver.extraClassPath",
                        "com.databricks-spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar")
  sparkLauncher.setConf("spark.executor.extraClassPath",
                        "com.databricks-spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar")
```

This is safe way to prevent spark runtime sql exceptions

Answer (score 0):

in spark cluster you need `spark-avro` jar file. you can download it from https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-avro. after downloading copy the file into `SPARK_HOME/jars` folder.